# Returning true/false from method

Tags: php

I have a class where before most methods (not all), I check if an id is valid. The purpose of each method in the class is to check various user details and each method returns true or false so other classes can check things.

```
public function doSomething($userId){

    $valid = false;

    if(empty($userId)){

        return $valid;
    }

    //do other stuff which may turn valid true

    return $valid;
}
```

So to tidy up the class I have moved this check from all the methods it appears in, to it's own method.

```
public function doSomething($userId){

    $valid = false;

    $this->idCheck($userId);

    //do other stuff

    return $valid;
}

private function idCheck($userId){

    if(empty($userId)){

        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If the id check fails, how could I get the method - doSomething to return? Would it be a further check inside this method:

```
if(!$this->idCheck($userId))return false;
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: no thats the way! use a simple `return` after your idCheck() returns false

Comment: Validate all the things in constructor (or when instantiating in factory) so to be sure than your instance is in consistence state

Comment: U can alter `idCheck` to just : `return empty($userId)`.As for your question. Don't track `$valid`. Just return false when needed and when everything checked out, `return true`

Answer (score 0):

You did it the right way. Just return your function if the ID is invalid. 
Otherwise - and thats even better, check your ID in the constructor!

```
public function __construct($userID)
{
    if(!empty($userID))
    {
        //do constructing things
    }
}
```

As DarkBee mentioned, you could rewrite your idCheck function into following:

```
private function idCheck($userID)
{
    return empty($userID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I check my id in the constructor? Won't this occur every time a method on the class is called? in this case it's no good for me as not all methods in the class require an ID check. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know the structure of your class but you get your ID from somewhere (mysql/as parameter/etc), right? So you do what you did in each method where you need an valid ID; run your `idCheck()`-method or use the simple `if(empty($id))` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
private function idCheck($userId)
 {

     $status=true;
    if(empty($userId))
       {

        $status=false;
       }

       return $status;


 }
```